# Bibtex entry for online resource is not shown correctly in the document

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I've used following entry in my `bibiliography.bib` file.

```
@misc{statistaAI,
  author = {Statista},
  title = {Worldwide Artificial Intelligent Market Revenues},
  year = 2020,
  url = {https://www.statista.com/statistics/607716/worldwide-artificial-intelligence-market-revenues/},
  urldate = {2020-02-04}
}
```

But it is displayed under references as follows, without any URL or accessed date.

> Statista, “Worldwide artificial intelligent market revenues,” 2020.

I'm using `ieeetr` bibliography style. Can someone help to identify the issue?

Comment: `ieeetr` is a style last significantly modified in the late eighties. URLs weren't a big thing back then (what with URLs only being standardised in the beginning of the nineties), so `ieeetr` simply does not have a `url` field. You can either take a more modern style that knows about URLs or you can put the URL and access date into the `howpublished` field like this `howpublished = {\url{https://www.statista.com/statistics/607716/worldwide-artificial-intelligence-market-revenues/} last accessed 4 Feb. 2020},`

Comment: @moewe This worked fine. If you can covert the comment to answer, I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*CW'd because it's a duplicate of the above comment. Answering so that the question can be accepted.*

`ieeetr` is a style last significantly modified in the late eighties. URLs weren't a big thing back then (what with URLs only being standardised in the beginning of the nineties), so `ieeetr` simply does not have a `url` field. You can either take a more modern style that knows about URLs or you can put the URL and access date into the `howpublished` field like this

```tex
howpublished = {\url{https://www.statista.com/statistics/607716/worldwide-artificial-intelligence-market-revenues/} last accessed 4 Feb. 2020},
```